# Error in replacing object of array with emptystring

Tags: iphone, ios

i am getting unpredictable error when two of `NSMutableArray` having same value at index 0 then i want to remove that object and replace object with empty string. But app get crash saying

```
 -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe2a06b0
  2012-03-22 14:36:48.181 golf eScorer[3849:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  
  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: 
   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe2a06b0'
```

When i debug using break point than log shows

```
2012-03-22 14:36:44.548 golf eScorer[3849:11f03] ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove....(
2
)
2012-03-22 14:36:44.549 golf eScorer[3849:11f03] discardedId...(
2
)
```

Here is my line of code:

```
 if([[ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[discardedId 
    objectAtIndex:0]])
        {
            [ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:emptyString];
        }
```

**Update:**

I solved like this

```
   NSMutableArray *ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove = [yournsarray mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the variable `ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove` is instance of `NSArray`. You can replace object in only in `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 0):

'__NSArrayI' - you have an immutable array here.

Its worth checking your implementation of the ArrayOfGameidOfPlayerToRemove arrray -make sure you have initalized an NSMutableArray rather than NSArray

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to remove /replace/modify contents of an array that is not mutable!